# Error Message in XML/Json in Play Framework

Tags: rest, playframework

I'm trying to develop a REST API for Play. I have two questions :

- Why does badRequest doesn't make it possible to add a message ?
- Though I set render.format = "json", the error message is written in plain text.
  Is it possible to wrap it into the format of render.format?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use the method

```
void error(int status, String reason)
```

to send back a message with http status code and a text message to the client.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you throw (Java) or return (Scala) BadRequest yourself or some software you are using does it implicitly. If it is you and all your consumers speak JSON probably you can return something like:

```json
{
     "error": "Error Text",
     "data": {
         "some": "data",
         "if": "everything",
         "works": "fine"
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On the first point, `BadRequest` is a class that sets the status code to 400 as per HTTP protocol. No extra message is required (nor can't be added in Play), browsers/clients should handle that.

On the second point, it would help to see the code, but please check that:

1. You call renderJson() to render
2. You have a template with the name method_called.json (like index.json for Application.index)
3. You are not setting the content type on the Response to something else than `application/json` before calling `renderJSON`

Comment: I don't *have* to add a message, but I would like to give some pointer to the client about why the request is not valid. (You forgot and arguments, your JSON post parameter is not valid etc.)

Comment: I am not calling renderJson. Actually BadRequest is an exception which is raised via badRequest, so my render() is not called at all.

However I set request.format beforehands, and was hopping for error handling to use this info.

Comment: @poulejapon probably the bad request hints to an issue with your routes file, can you try to access the url via the browser and see the error shown?

Comment: It should always be possible to send a message body to client.